# Javascript accidental closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, closures

I have this piece of code on my website which counts the number of image and then output a list each time the user clicks on desired category.

The problem is, my image counter variable (noIMG) does not clear itself every time the function is called. I tried adding a reset(noIMG) at the end of the function but it seemed like a bad idea.

I did some research and i've stumbled upon articles about closures. After trying numerous methods to fix it, my code is still not acting the way I want it to.

---

```
function thumbCounter(){

    var noIMG = $(".artwork img").size()+1;

        for (var count = 1; count < noIMG; count++){
            if (count == 1){
                 $('#list_here').append('<li class="active">' +count+ '</li>');
            } else{
                 $('#list_here').append('<li>' +count+ '</li>');    
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clear itself"? `count` is your counter variable. That's the variable that you want to restart from 1 every time you invoke the function. `noIMG` is expected to be the same each time you invoke the function, unless you modify the DOM in between, to add images. But perhaps this is not what you're asking?

Comment: You may be shadowing a different `noIMG` variable (or window property). In this code, out of context, there is no closure, accidental or otherwise -- but in context, well, that may be an entirely different story!

Comment: Your problem is not visible here - can you try and reproduce it on http://jsfiddle.net/ to show us?

Comment: The counter I want to clear is noIMG. I call it by using  "thumbCounter();"

Comment: @James: what do you mean by wanting to clear the `noIMG` "counter"? Each time you call `thumbCounter` the value of `noIMG` will be set to the total number of images contained in an `.artwork` element. Do you want to change the DOM, and physically remove all such images? Do you want `noIMG` to work in some other way? In that case what way? Do you want `noIMG` to work as I described it, but are currently experiencing some other behavior? In that case what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to clear the list every time the function is called, then do it like this:

```
function thumbCounter() {
    var noIMG = $(".artwork img").size() + 1;
    var myList = $('#list_here'); // reference to list

    myList.html(""); // clear the contents
    for (var count = 1; count < noIMG; count++) {
        if (count == 1) {
             myList.append('<li class="active">' +count+ '</li>');
        } else {
             myList.append('<li>' +count+ '</li>');    
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I am using $("#selector ul").empty(); to clear the list. The thing is, it's noIMG that I need to reset to 0 every time the function is called. For some reason, noIMG saves the last number that was obtained and whenever the function is called - it adds it on top of the exisitng number. It displays correct amount when called first time, i.e 6; second time it becomes 12, and so on...

Comment: OK, too bad this wasn't what you were looking for. Are you sure you aren't doing something to the DOM, like adding stuff that would be matched by $(".artwork img")? Put a full example up on jsfiddle or jsbin, that might explain things.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. It seems there was indeed a mix up with a similar selector.

Comment: Good! You might want to mark this question as answered then, to prevent others from trying to spot the error.